# Custom Iterator in Datastore shows zero using JAVA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I used my datastore entity to store an int value number=0. In an add function I used count = number++. But first time app push to GAE, it shows 0. Then it start from 1. So I changed as int number =10 even though I get the value is zero but datastore store as 10. How can I get the updated value in java page after inserting a record? When I try to get the **current** value, it shows zero but in datastore it store as 10. Please help me to out this problem. how to get value 10. This happens only at the first time of deploy and first ticket only then it shows correct value (iterator value)

thanks

here my code

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    //static int nextID = 17;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      private String title;  
      private Text description;
      static int nextID = 10;
      private int current;


      public Ticket(String title, Text description) {
            current = nextID++;
            this.title = title;
            this.priority = priority;
            this.description = description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform has multiple datacenters and they do not always hold the same state of the same record. This is especially true if you query for the value immediately after increasing it. You can use ancestor queries to retrieve the Entity, that will make it up to date and consistent. Please look at the article [1] for details.

Here's a link with ancestor query [2]. The idea is that when you use an ancestor query, it forces the query to return data after all changes are finalized (for that query). This ensures up-to-date strong consistency.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Ancestor_queries

===---=== Example (from the 2nd link I provided)

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Entity tom = new Entity("Person", "Tom");
Key tomKey = tom.getKey();
datastore.put(tom);


Entity weddingPhoto = new Entity("Photo", tomKey);
weddingPhoto.setProperty("imageURL",
                         "http://domain.com/some/path/to/wedding_photo.jpg");

Entity babyPhoto = new Entity("Photo", tomKey);
babyPhoto.setProperty("imageURL",
                      "http://domain.com/some/path/to/baby_photo.jpg");

Entity dancePhoto = new Entity("Photo", tomKey);
dancePhoto.setProperty("imageURL",
                       "http://domain.com/some/path/to/dance_photo.jpg");

Entity campingPhoto = new Entity("Photo");
campingPhoto.setProperty("imageURL",
                         "http://domain.com/some/path/to/camping_photo.jpg");

List<Entity> photoList = Arrays.asList(weddingPhoto, babyPhoto,
                                       dancePhoto, campingPhoto);
datastore.put(photoList);


Query photoQuery = new Query("Photo")
                         .setAncestor(tomKey);  


// This returns weddingPhoto, babyPhoto, and dancePhoto,
// but not campingPhoto, because tom is not an ancestor
List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(photoQuery)
                                .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

===---===
See these parts:

Entity weddingPhoto = new Entity("Photo", tomKey);

Entity dancePhoto = new Entity("Photo", tomKey);

This generates an Entity with an ancestor key "tomKey".

Now save the Entities into the Datastore:

```
List<Entity> photoList = Arrays.asList(weddingPhoto, babyPhoto,
                                           dancePhoto, campingPhoto);
datastore.put(photoList);
```

When you need to fetch the results, perform a special query:

```
Query photoQuery = new Query("Photo")
                             .setAncestor(tomKey);
```

This makes sure the photoQuery isn't just a random query aimed at any random datacenter pulling out any data; it makes sure it fetches the up-to-date data from the datastore.

Comment: I'm new one for GAE using java. I cant understand ancestor query. Please explain with example. I'm using DAO and javax.persistence.Query. using this  give example

Comment: Please use the datastore query methods for ancestor queries (as the example showed).

The idea is that when you provide an ancestor key to an Entity and then later on query it using the ancestor key. It will return the up-to-date version of the entity.

Comment: ok thanks for giving example. Im not asking primary key. Im going to create custom iterator. is it help for custom iterator?

Comment: Ok, your original problem was that your custom iterator has out-of-date data from time to time, right?

The reason is because when you query for the iterator (to add to it), you sometimes find the outdated version. So using Ancestor Query, you make sure that you get the updated version of your saved iterator.

Example: if x=0, x++, fetch x will give you x=1 IF you fetch it using ancestor query, IF you fetch it with normal query, it could still be x=0.

Comment: WOW SUPER EXPLANATION. NOW ONLY I GET KNOWLEDGE THANKS. I ALREADY USED javax.persistence.Query. CAN I USE NOW? OR CAN I CHANGE MY PROJECT.

Comment: The query method is fine. Just make sure you add the ancestor key to the query attribute. Like this line:

Query photoQuery = new Query("Photo")
                             .setAncestor(tomKey);

However, if your data structure doesn't contain ancestors, then you will need to reconstruct your entities so they are all attached to an ancestor.